# Does foo.Include(x => x.bar.Select(y => y.baz) include foo.bar in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can I use `foo.Include(x => x.Bar.Select(y => y.Baz)` to include `foo.Bar` but also `foo.Bar.Baz`? Or do I have to use `foo.Include(x => x.Bar).Include(x => x.Bar.Select(y => y.Baz))`?

**Solution:** *(Thanks to [atlasmaybe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2699126/atlasmaybe))*

`foo.Include(x => x.Bar.Select(y => y.Baz)` includes both `foo.Bar` AND `foo.Bar.Baz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It clearly depends on you data model and your ORM. But I'm gonna assume you're using Entity Framework and that your model looks like this one:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar 
{
    public virtual List<Baz> Baz { get; set; }
}

public class Baz
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

If so, then `foo.Include(f => f.Bar.Select(b => b.Baz))` will include `Bar` AND `Baz`.

Comment: Could you give an example where `Bar` would not be included automatically?

Comment: If you want `Baz`, you'll always get `Bar` with it, with this model and using `Include`. If you want to avoid `Bar` you should build a custom EF query and disable Lazy Loading. But I don't think it's the purpose of this question initialy...

Comment: Yes, I use EF indeed. Thank you for the solution to my question.